# Unity 4.x: How to Access AnimationState in Mecanim

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm using Mecanim Animation System in Unity 4.5.x. I have an Animator component on a GameObject called "VictorSprite", with several layers, each layer has several AnimationStates.

How can I access each AnimationState to change its properties, specifically speed?

Unfortunately, most of the documents I can find are deprecated, and don't refer to Mecanim. I have also tried this code:

```
AnimationState animState = GameObject.Find("VictorSprite").GetComponent<Animator>().animation["VictorTalk"];
```

But, I receive this error message:

```
"MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "VictorSprite" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "VictorSprite". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it."
```

Unity 3.x Animation component is deprecated and is not recommended anymore in Unity 4.x.

p.s. I tried this code too, but it doesn't provide good functionality:

```
AnimatorStateInfo animState = GameObject.Find("VictorSprite").GetComponent<Animator>().GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(2);
```

p.s. 2: Basically, I'm applying multiple animations in different layers on a game object, and I want to be able to pause one of them dynamically. Setting its weight to 0 is not helpful, because it "resets" the animation, instead of pausing.

Answer (score 1):

To speed up,

```
    var animator = unityChan.GetComponent<Animator> ();
    animator.speed = 10.0f;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want.

```
Animator animator = GameObject.Find("ObjectInScene").GetComponent<Animator>();
AnimationInfo[] stateInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimationClipState(index);
```

However, it is a bit unclear why you would actually want this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but unfortunately it's not helping. AnimationInfo class does not have a "speed" field that I can set to 0.

Comment: Here is the story, I have a 2D sprite, and sometimes 2 animations are applied to the object at the same time. One changes the scale, the other one makes it bounce. I want to be able to pause one of them, based on the logic of the game.

Comment: Simply, in other words, how to pause a playing animation state, in an Animator with multiple additive layers.